# how to a href a page made a starter kit thats in another folder

Tags: html, css, sass, gulp-sass

Hi this might be confusing, sorry in advance.

I'm creating a resume website and I'm trying to show the past projects I've made.
The only problem is that I've made some of them with a starter kit that used gulp sass. When trying to link those pages I only get the html and not the scss.

ps: still in testing phase.. I know it switches from netflix to facebook

Clicking this:

[image]

leads to this page:

[image]

This page was made with a starter kit but only shows the html.